# How to updating product list from dropdown react/redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to understand how to filter a list of items with react/redux. I've build this example https://codesandbox.io/s/m3n0x7mqzj
i want when i click on the category the products category_id is equal to category id and then return the products of same id's

**action.js :-**

```
export const selectCategory = (data) => {
console.log("You clicked on category: ", data.name);
return {
    type: 'CATEGORY_SELECTED',
    payload: data 

}
```

};

**reducer-category.js**

```
export default function (state = null, action) {
switch (action.type) {
    case 'CATEGORY_SELECTED':
        return action.payload; 

    default:
        break;
}
return state;
```

}

**category.js**:-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
 import {connect} from 'react-redux';
 import {selectCategory} from '../actions/index';

    class Category extends Component{

   renderList() {
    return this.props.Data.categories.map((user) => {
        return (

            <option
                key={user.id}
                onClick={() => this.props.selectCategory(user)}
            > 
                {user.name} 

            </option>
        );
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <select>

            {this.renderList()}
        </select>
    );
}
  }


  function mapStateToProps(state) {
   return {
    Data: state.Data
     };
    }


function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
return bindActionCreators({selectCategory: selectCategory}, dispatch);
}
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(Category);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your question? Looks very vague and hard to comprehend. 

Probably in points would help

Comment: I was working on your codesandbox but you deleted your question! There're so many mistake on your project. Most things are wrong. Reducers, states, actions, lifecycles... You should work on redux and react again. I'll give working example from your sandbox, DON'T DELETE QUESTION please.

Comment: @akcoban Ohh really sorry i dont know that you are working on my codesandbox plz give me the working  example link

Comment: @SyedSadaifRizvi i want to ask you a question. Why you store your data in reducer? Normally do you get your data from ajax request?

Comment: @akcoban how i can add validation just for numbers on input field  https://codesandbox.io/s/5pn421y2p

Comment: @SyedSadaifRizvi snippet updated, check again

Comment: @akcoban want to show this NO STOCK validation below the comment when the user insert input above then the available

Comment: Did you try anything? I think you can do this or create something?@SyedSadaifRizvi

Comment: @akcoban yes i try but nothing happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn lots of thing about redux and react.

- Set your all states in redux, not in component's state.
- `onChange` function should be on `select` element, i didn't
  understand why you use `onClick` on `option` elements.
- Use `componentWillMount()` or `componentDidMount()` to fetch data for
  first time on component. Use redux actions inside that lifecycle
  methods.
- Set initial state on your reducer files and change it from actions.

These are my remarks. Hope this can help! Here is the working example for you. Review this.

https://codesandbox.io/s/6wr900jq8r

Comment: Thansk :) @akcoban

Comment: can you plz check this link https://codesandbox.io/s/51l3p03mp i want when i write in quantity field then the quantity is added in the sold and subtracted from the available

Comment: @SyedSadaifRizvi https://codesandbox.io/s/vv15xx563l like that. That's a basic way. And also you can manipulate your functions and datas from app.js not in components. Such as, send data via props to products component.

Comment: can you plz check my json data file reducer-data.js in this file a portion discount i want when we write quantity in input then the discount will be act upon it @akcoban

Comment: You can update your data which in reducer but when you deleted quantity value, available and sold data will not change to default. For example: Available: 10 and you wrote 5 to quantity input. When you change your input to 4, available will be 1. The best practice i think, update reducer data when clicked an update button. If you want this, i can edit codesandbox.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/q7y4zr40lj simple example to change reducer data

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/x722156rwo    @akcoban check this link i want this type of thing according to json file